# Adobe After Effects MP4 Export Issue

Tags: video, after-effects, codec, encoding

I'm trying to export a composition from Adobe After Effects. My Comp is 1280x720, and ideally I'd export with an mp4 container, and h264 video codec. Problem is, After Effects is giving me a PAR error, telling me the video will be resized "to meet format contraints".

Error Message:

> Video will be resized from 1280x720(1.00PAR) to 176x120(1.21PAR) to meet format constraints.

Anyone know of a fix to this? Looks like my encoder is MainConcept MP4 Video. I'm using CS6. Thanks!

Comment: Could you elaborate on how you are choosing the container and video codec? An overview of the steps you're taking would help answer the question. Because when I choose the `H264` output module in the After Effects renderer I get a `.mp4` file with no PAR (Pixel Aspect Ratio) errors.

Answer (score 2):

In AE's "output module settings", with the format set to h.264, click "format options".  Under the "video" tab, make sure "Level" is set to 5.1.

[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H.264/MPEG-4_AVC) is a wikipedia entry which contains a table on h.264 level dimension constraints.

Comment: it works! thank you

Comment: This most likely won't get seen, Being a little late. About 2 years late. But thanks so much Jason, I've never had this issue before and resolving it was just completely unknown to me. I don't know why it happened as I was rendering videos completely fine the day before, Thanks again.

Comment: Very very useful Information. Successful method. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are using a trial version of an encoder that imposes limitations on the size it will export based on the severe down-scaling that it is imposing.